# online software to draw generic graphics for calculus and analysis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-software

could you mention any software in which I could design images like this.
[image]

Comment: Desmos is good for 2D graphs. You can try Geogebra as well, although I'm not exactly sure how good it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the packages **[pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/)**  or **[TikZ](https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/TikZ_package)** in Latex. They are very powerful. You can see some examples [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) .

Answer (score 1):

[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) is (imho) one of the best 
open-source 3d graphic tools designed specifically for this task.
It is part of the TeXLive distribution, 
and deeply interacts with LaTeX to render the labels.

This image

[image]

was constructed (programmed) in terms of 3d lines, curves and surfaces 
with the following code:

```
//    
// sph.asy    
//
size(6cm);
import solids;

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(5,1.5,2),up=Z,
target=(0.6,0.6,0.7),zoom=1);

import fontsize; defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pen linePen=darkblue+0.9bp;
pen line2Pen=red+0.7bp;
pen dashPen=gray(0.3)+0.8bp+linetype(new real[] {5,5});

arrowbar3 arr=Arrow3(size=3.0);

real r=1;
real amin=0, amax=1.3r;

guide3 arcxy=Arc(O,(r,0,0),(0,r,0));
guide3 arcxw=Arc(O,(r,0,0),(0,0,r));

real a=0.7r,b=1.3r;
real phi=30;
triple p0=(0,r-a,0);
triple p1=rotate(-phi,Z)*(0,r,0);
triple p2=(p1.x,p1.y,b);
triple p3=(p0.x,p0.y,b);
triple p4=(0,p0.y,sqrt(r^2-p0.y^2));

guide3 arcyw1=Arc(O,p4,(0,0,r));

surface sr=surface(revolution(arcxw,Z,0.0,90.0)); 

triple v=p0*(1-0.5)+p1*0.5;
triple p5=intersectionpoints(v--(v+(0,0,b)),sr)[0];

guide3 arccut=p1..p5..p4;

triple p6=point(arccut,0.8);
triple p7=(0,p0.y,p6.z);
triple p8=(p6.x,p6.y,0);

guide3 arcyw23=Arc(O,(0,r,0),p4);

v=currentprojection.target-currentprojection.camera;
real[][] q=intersections(arcyw23,
  surface(p1--(p1+v)--(p2+v)--p2--cycle)
);

triple p9=point(arcyw23,q[0][0]);

guide3 arcyw2=subpath(arcyw23,0,q[0][0]);
guide3 arcyw3=subpath(arcyw23,q[0][0],length(arcyw23));

draw(arcyw2,linePen);
draw(arcyw3,dashPen);

draw(arcxy,linePen);
draw(arcxw,linePen);
draw(arcyw1,linePen);
draw(arccut,linePen);

draw(p4--p0--p1,dashPen);
draw(p8--p6--p7,dashPen);

draw(p1--p2--p3--p4,linePen);

draw(O--(r,0,0),dashPen);
draw(O--(0,r,0),dashPen);
draw(O--(0,0,r),dashPen);

real d=1.3r;
draw((r,0,0)--(d,0,0),line2Pen,arr);
draw((0,r,0)--(0,d,0),line2Pen,arr);
draw((0,0,r)--(0,0,d),line2Pen,arr);
draw(p1--(p1+0.3*(p1-p0)),line2Pen,arr);

dot(p0--p4--p6--p7--p8);

label("$x$",(amax,0,0),X);
label("$y$",(0,amax,0),Y);
label("$w$",(0,0,amax),Z);

label("$P_0$",p0,X-Z);

label("$\Delta w$",(p4+p7)/2,-Y);
label("$\Delta s$",(p6+p7)/2,-Z);
label("$\Delta s$",(p0+p8)/2,-Z);
label("$u$",p1,Y-2Z);
```

Run

```
asy -f pdf -noprc -render=0 sph.asy
```

to get a vector graphic sph.pdf image.